# Laravel Feature Test - Inserting Data

Tags: testing, eloquent, automated-tests, laravel-8

I have a metadata table and need to test inserting data:

```
public function test_insert_unique_data()
{
    $response = Metadata::create([
        'metable_id' => '1',
        'metable_type' => File::class,
        'type' => 'resolution',
        'key' => 'width',
        'value' => 1000,
    ]);

    $response->assertCreated();
}
```

This is the migration for the table:

```
Schema::create(..., function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('metable_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->string('metable_type')->index();
    $table->string('type')->default('default');
    $table->string('key')->index();
    $table->text('value');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

It's failing every time so I can only assume the test is written wrong. Any pointers please?

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?

Comment: PHPUnit, Laravel default

Comment: See my answer. Could you maybe provide the migration for `Metadata` ? Do you want to specifically test creating a `Metadata` object without factories and therefore with mass assignment protection?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the migration. Using/not using factories isn't a specific requirement although I don't have anything extra setup, I'm just wanting to test the insertion of data in the simplest way. I'm new to unit testing database interactions.

Comment: The difference is the mass assignment protection. You probably heard of the `$guarded` array or the `$fillable` array inside your models. With them you can specify which attributes of a model can be assigned in your `create` or `update` statements. Using a factory disables this protection. There is no harm in doing it manually tho. [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a factory? They have all sorts of assertions in their [Database testing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#available-assertions) section.

Unless there's a reason for it, every testing that uses any models I'm seeing in modern Laravel (I come from Laravel 3-5 days) is using factories.

Comment: Well his test is named `test_insert_unique_data`. Other than that a factory would probably be preferable, at least when this is not the only test for metadata. Also one thing to consider is that mass assignment protection is automatically disabled when creating models using factories.

Comment: I want to link [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) regarding state reset because that's why I recommended factory. If OP is just using the model, it's hard to tell what could be happening and it could even be writing to the database directly w/o refreshing which is not good for a feature test, especially if you go to check the data. You don't have to make a lot, you can just make a single record with a factory and override those attributes. Mass assignment protection is a meh point considering this is just a feature test.

Comment: And based on the name, like you mentioned, and the `assertCreated` if there's no refreshing of the database, etc. Then the test will pass once, then fail the rest theoretically because the record wasn't created because it's not "unique" although based on the schema there's no unique checking so realistically every test would pass.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about this `assertCreated` function but I know of something similar:

```php
public function test_insert_unique_data()
{
    $metadata = Metadata::create([
        'metable_id' => '1',
        'metable_type' => File::class,
        'type' => 'resolution',
        'key' => 'width',
        'value' => 1000,
    ]);

    $this->assertModelExists($metadata);
}
```